# Обрезать ссылки до имени файла

Tags: jquery

Есть некоторе количество ссылок на файлы, которые лежат в блоках (div > li > a). Их надо  обрезать до названия файла, т.е. сайт.ру/.../имя_файла.жпг -> имя_файла.жпг

Как надо изменить этот код, что бы он работал для каждой ссылки, а не только для первой?

```
 $("#file a").each(function() {
                $(this).html($("#file a").html().split("/")[7]);
            })
```

## file - id для li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#file a").each(function() {
  var parts = $(this).attr("href").split("/");
  $(this).text(parts[parts.length - 1]);
});
```